# openfl - android black screen if resuming after a while

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I am developing an android game with openfl. 
When I test it on my phone, it starts up fine. Now if I deactivate the game app and return to it after a short while it shows a black screen for less than a second then returns to the game.

However, if the game app stays in the background for around 10mins, then if I open it up again it shows a black screen, then the game comes up after waiting for 15 seconds or it doesn't come up at all - just a black screen. (At this point, android is not frozen since I can pull down the notification bar.)

Also there is a music in the game, and it does resume playing during the black screen.

Does any one have any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading openfl to 4.4.1 and lime to 3.4.1 get rids of this problem.